# Decrypt and encrypt a file using gpg without re-typing the passphrase

Tags: linux, command-line, encryption, gnupg, passphrase

[**Notice**: my problem is similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198484/310237). And related to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/469518/310237)]

Basically I want to edit a symmetrically encrypted filed and then encrypt it again using the same passphrase, without the need to retype it.

It goes like this:

```
gpg --output $file_to_edit --decrypt $ecrypted_file
echo "Some edit" >> $file_to_edit
gpg --output $ecrypted_file --symmetric $file_to_edit
```

Now, `gpg` asks 3 times for the passphrase (1 for decryption and 2 for encryption). What I'd like is to type the passphrase only once (for decryption) and, if it's correct, use it again for encryption. Is there a *secure* way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several options, but they all could leave you with a decrypted file on disk, waiting to be undeleted later. Shred might even have problems securely deleting a file (if there's a log/journal, redundant writes / RAID, temporary caches, compressed filesystems) and an SSD could swap sectors silently too. Even using a `tmpfs` filesystem is subject to being written out to swap. And the editing program you use could leave even more temporary/cache files. If your entire filesystem and swap is encrypted that helps a lot, but then do you really need more encryption?

If you're just saving basic text (like passwords) I'd suggest using a purpose-built program like KeePass(X/XC), LastPass, etc. Or a different encryption method, one that encrypts files like eCryptfs, EncFS, or that encrypts devices like LUKS, or a TrueCrypt successor.

---

But with just GPG, you could use one of these options

- `--passphrase-fd n`
            Read the passphrase from file descriptor n. Only the first line  will  be
            read  from  file descriptor n. If you use 0 for n, the passphrase will be
            read from STDIN. This can only be used if only  one  passphrase  is  supplied.

  Note  that  this  passphrase  is only used if the option --batch has also
            been given.  This is different from GnuPG version 1.x.
- `--passphrase-file file`
            Read the passphrase from file `file`. Only the first line will be read from
            file  `file`.  This  can  only  be used if only one passphrase is supplied.
            Obviously, a passphrase stored in a file is of questionable  security  if
            other  users  can  read this file. Don't use this option if you can avoid
            it.  Note that this passphrase is only used if  the  option  --batch  has
            also been given.  This is different from GnuPG version 1.x.
- `--passphrase string`
            Use  string  as  the  passphrase.  This  can  only  be  used  if only one
            passphrase is supplied. Obviously, this is of very questionable  security
            on  a multi-user system. Don't use this option if you can avoid it.  Note
            that this passphrase is only used if the option  --batch  has  also  been
            given.  This is different from GnuPG version 1.x.

For the above options, you'll probably need either `--pinentry-mode loopback` (allows entering new info, for example a new filename if there's a conflict) or `--batch` otherwise gpg will just ignore the passphrase options and still ask the agent for a passphrase (a bug IMO).
This might be useful too:

- `--passphrase-repeat n`
            Specify how many times gpg will request a  new  passphrase  be  repeated.
            This  is useful for helping memorize a passphrase.  Defaults to 1 repetition.

---

You could only type the passphrase once and `read` / store it in a shell/bash variable (say `$password`), recalling it later with `--passphrase="$password"`. Something like

```
until gpg --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase="$password" --output $file_to_edit $ecrypted_file;
do read -r password;
done

#Got out of the loop with a correct password, now
echo "Some edit" >> $file_to_edit

gpg --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase="$password" --output $ecrypted_file --yes --symmetric $file_to_edit
```

(`--yes` to overwrite)

Comment: Note: `--pinentry-mode` is available only for gpg 2.x (not for gpg 1.x). Also, there's no need for `--batch` option with gpg 1.x.

Comment: That's true, with gpg 1  --passphrase [& --passphrase-file & --passphrase-fd] actually worked without needing extra tricks ;-) Another surprise is that gpg will remember the passphrase for a while (minutes?) and decrypt the same file again *without* asking for the passphrase